# .Net Core project accesses too many class or API when it depends on some other projects

Tags: .net-core-2.0, .net-standard-2.0

I have two .Net Standard 2.0 library projects: `Lib1` and `Lib2`, `Lib2` depends on `Lib1`, `Lib1` has class `Class1`, `Lib2` has class `Class2`. Then I create a .Net Core 2.0 and a .Net Framework project:

- The .Net Core 2.0 console application project named `DevInNetCore`
  which only depends on `Lib2`, but `Lib1.Class1` can be accessed in this
  project.
- The .Net Framework 4.6.1 console application project named
  `DevInNetFramework` which also only depends on `Lib2`, but now
  `Lib1.Class1` can't be accessed in this project.

My question is: Why `Lib1.Class1` can be accessed in the .Net Core project `DevInNetCore` since it only depends on project `Lib2`? Is there any way to let `Lib1` can not be accessed in the project `DevInNetCore`?

Here is my demo solution: https://www.dropbox.com/s/u60xjl3i37arcs2/LibTest.zip?dl=0, **Visual Studio 2017** may be needed to load the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why Lib1.Class1 can be accessed in the .Net Core project DevInNetCore
>   since it only depends on project Lib2?

This change came with new format of `csproj` files. Here is [related issue](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/199) on github. If you check the references in Visual Studio, you will see that for .Net Core project VS 'knows' that `Lib2` depends on `Lib1`. However this is not the case for reference from .Net Framework project.

[image]

So answering your question "Why ..." - because it's the feature that was implemented for new project format and not for the legacy one.

> Is there any way to let Lib1 can not be accessed in the project
>   DevInNetCore?

Here is [related discussion](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6635) on github. I agree with [Eilon's comment](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/6635#issuecomment-321024811) that such restriction should not take a place in general. However if you still want to do it, you could make types of `Lib1` internal and then allow access them from `Lib2` with `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute.